# Configure Gmail as SMTP in Xampp to send mail -Got Error.Why?

Tags: php, gmail, xampp, email

I am following [this](http://fordflux.com/blog/how-to/php-sendmail-and-xampp-on-windows/) instruction and I got the same error like a first user comment.And I dont know how to fix this error.

Short notes what I did.

1.Change the sendmail.ini and php.ini settings for sending mail
 2.Put the dlls on the send mail folder
 3.Put my username and password from my gmail account

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465


; SMTPS (SSL) support
; auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
; ssl = alway use SSL
; tls = always use TLS
; none = never try to use SSL
;smtp_ssl=auto
smtp_ssl=tls
default_domain=brettshaffer.com
error_logfile=error.log
```

Tried both tsl and ssl same error.Error is below.

```
10/12/07 18:03:36 : Connection Closed Gracefully.
```

Updated

```
auth_username=myname@gmail.com
auth_password=mypassword
```

I already put there and also I put two ssl dlls for that SSL connection

```
libeay32.dll
ssleay32.dll
```

Comment: Gmail requires authentication. Did you set auth_username and auth_password in your sendmail.ini? And did you try smtp.googlemail.com as well?

Comment: Pleas see the updated question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

since you are using xampp it would be easier to use phpmailer script:

[PHP-Mailer script](http://deepakssn.blogspot.com/2006/06/gmail-php-send-email-using-php-with.html)

and if you insist on using xampp you should set:
smtp_ssl = ssl

and configure the sendmail.ini so that it connects with your @gmail.com account credentials. or it will not be able to connect.

Comment: Could you also post the last few lines of you apache error log, and email log?

Comment: 10/12/07 18:03:36 : Connection Closed Gracefully.
When I execute the code in browser I got a error like maximum execution time is exceed.But I think(max_execution_time=60) is enough for sending mail.Is it correct or I need to increase the execution time

Comment: I used mailer script and Its now sending the email